# Ext js4 multi level grouping

Tags: extjs

Hello friends I would like to know if there is any way to apply multi-level grouping in Ext js4. I have studied the grouping feature for grids but I found that it is applicable only for single level grouping. Is there any pre-defined way or we are supposed to use User extensions?

Comment: Does the treegrid (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/treegrid.html) ux do what you want?

Comment: Actually no. By multi-level grouping I am expecting that grouping should be applied on multiple columns of a grid at a time. Ex- if name,age,birth date are the columns then grouping could be done on age and birth date at a time.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to what you're looking for but a step in the right directory. Hope that help. http://www.learnsomethings.com/2011/10/25/grouping-on-multiple-columns-in-extjs-4/

Comment: Check this link out. It might help
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?226739-MultiGrouping-and-MultiGroupingSummary